# Keras - how to set weights to some layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, federated-learning

I want to set weights to an existing model, such as VGG 16. However, I only want to set weights to the model **excluding the last (fully connected) layer**. I have tried to use `model.layers[:-1].set_weights(weights[:-1])`, it will cause the error of

```
File "server.py", line 114, in evaluate                                                                                   
model.layers[:-1].set_weights(weights[:-1])          
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_weights'
```

There is one solution used the for loop to set the weight, but it is inefficient.

```
weights_list = model.get_weights()
for i, weights in enumerate(weights_list[0:9]):
    model.layers[i].set_weights(weights)
```

Is there a way to set the weight to some layers of the model? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://www.codespeedy.com/get_weights-and-set_weights-functions-in-keras-layers/) reference help you to solve your issue? Also check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#saving_loading_only_the_models_weights_values) link for more detailed information on setting weights.

Comment: @TFer2  Thank you for your answer. The first reference is not fully correct. I have solved this issue. I will post a detailed solution later. Thanks!